# Need another phrase for fit in (as in a group)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What other word or words can be used to replace "fit in"? E.g. "I believe I will *fit in* with your organization."

Comment: Suit: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/suit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Comment: All suggestions below are good replacements for 'fit in'.  However, I think you're over-thinking it and still prefer 'fit in'.  But I would re-write the sentence as "I believe I'm a good fit for your organization".  That sounds much more natural than replacing fit with any of the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> [Jibe](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jibe): to be in harmony or accord; agree.

Or any of these synonyms: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/jibe

Answer (score 1):

Assimilate - To become or allow something to become a part of a country or community rather than remaining in separate groups. Eg. New arrivals find it hard  to assimilate.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer a couple of suggestions that would work well in the context you gave (all definitions chosen for the appropriate context from dictionary.com):

**mesh**

> to match, coordinate, or interlock:
> The two versions of the story don't mesh.

**integrate**

> 1. to bring together or incorporate (parts) into a whole.
> 2. to make up, combine, or complete to produce a whole or a larger unit, as parts do.
> 3. to unite or combine.

**relate**

> to establish a social or sympathetic relationship with a person or thing:
> two sisters unable to relate to each other.

*Integrate* would probably be my chosen verb for describing the ability to work well with co-workers in order to complete a project in a professional setting. When talking about how well people *relate* to one another, I believe it invokes a more personal connotation.

Answer (score 0):

Conform - "behave according to socially acceptable conventions or standards".  See https://www.google.com/search?q=conform ; "fit in" is listed as a synonym